# Hiding A Table From Gmail's "Display Images Below"

Tags: html, css, gmail, media-queries, html-email

I'm developing an HTML email that utilizes two columns for the desktop design and one for the mobile design. Instead of dealing with all the complexity of targeting specific elements of the desktop version with media queries and trying to make them work for mobile (doing this is a nightmare with emails..), I figured I'd make a completely separate table for mobile and make the desktop version disappear (display: none), at a breakpoint of below 450px.

Now, this works; however, on desktop (above 450px), where I set the mobile table to (display none; display: none !important;) there comes a problem. When opening the email on a screen size larger than 450px (IN GMAIL, not in a browser. I'm using a service called "freshmail" to test this), initially only the desktop table appears; however, none of the images are present. Gmail asks "Display Images Below" and clicking this rewrites my style-sheets such that the mobile table appears as well even though I explicitly tell it not too.

I know this is a tricky business, and I've tried many workarounds to overcome it, but none have worked. If anyone could help me accomplish this I would very much appreciate it.

My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

        <title></title>

        <style>

        @media (min-width: 451px) {
            #mobile {
                display: none;
                display: none !important;
            }
        }

        @media (max-width: 450px) {
            #desktop {
                display: none !important;
            }

            #mobile {
                display: block !important;
            }
        }

        </style>

    </head>


    <body style="width: 100% !important; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 13.5px; line-height: 1.4; font-family: Helvetica; overflow-x: hidden;">
        <table id="desktop" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="1px solid black">
            <tr>
                <td  style="display: block; clear: both !important; margin: 0 auto !important; width: 600px !important; overflow: hidden;">
                    <table  border="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;">

                        <tr style="">
                            <th>

                            </th>
                            <th style="padding-top: 20px;">
                                <span style="color: #504e4b;"/>
                                    example text                            
                                </span>
                            </th>
                        </tr>

                        <tr style="padding: 0; background: #ffffff; color: #504e4b;">
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <a href='#' style="cursor: default;"><img src="assets/example.gif" style="display: block;"></a>
                                <a href='#' style="cursor: default;"><img src="assets/example.gif" style="display: block; pointer-events: none; cursor: default;"></a>
                                <span style="display: block; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 200; text-transform: uppercase; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 30px; color: #f36b22;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                                <span style="display: block; font-size: 35px; font-weight: 900; line-height: 1; text-transform: uppercase; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 30px;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                                <span style="display: block; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 200; padding-left: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr style="padding: 0; background: #ffffff;">
                            <td style="width: 50%; padding: 0px; border: none;">
                                <a href='#' style="cursor: default;"><img src="assets/example.png" style="display: block;"></a>
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 0px; border: none;">

                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr style="height: 415px; color: #504e4b;">
                            <td style="padding: 0px; width: 50%; background-color: #fccb03; vertical-align: top;">
                                <a href='#' style="cursor: default;"><img src="assets/example.png" style="display: block;"></a>
                                <span style="display: block; height: 10px;"></span>
                                <span style="display: block; font-size: 28px; font-weight: 900; line-height: 1; text-transform: uppercase; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 20px;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                                <span style="display: block; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-bottom: 50px; font-weight: 200; color: #504e4b;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 0px;">
                                <a href='#' style="cursor: default;"><img src="assets/example.gif" style="display: block;"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr style="vertical-align: top; color: #504e4b;">
                            <td style="width: 50%; padding: 0px; border: none;">
                                <a href='#' style="cursor: default;"><img src="assets/example.png" style="display: block;"></a>
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: right; padding: 0px;">
                                <a href='#' style="cursor: default;"><img src="assets/example.png" align="right" style="display: block; padding-right: 20px;"></a>
                                <span style="display: block; font-size: 28px; font-weight: 900; line-height: 1; text-transform: uppercase; margin-top: 180px; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-right: 20px;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                                <span style="display: block; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-bottom: 40px; font-weight: 200; color: #504e4b;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                                <a href='#' style="cursor: default;"><img src="assets/example.png" align="right" style="display: block;"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr style="padding: 0; background: #f36b22; color: #ffffff;">
                            <td>
                                <span style="display: block; font-size: 28px; font-weight: 900; line-height: 1; text-transform: uppercase; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 30px; padding-top: 50px;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                                <span style="display: block; padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 20px; padding-bottom: 50px; font-weight: 200;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 0px;">
                                <a href='#' style="cursor: default;"><img src="assets/example.png" style="display: block;"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr style="padding: 0; background: #ffffff;">
                            <td style="padding: 0px; border: none;">

                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 50%; padding: 0px; border: none;">
                                <a href='#' style="cursor: default;"><img src="assets/example.png" align="right" style="display: block;"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr style="color: #504e4b;">
                            <td align="center" colspan="2" style="padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px;">
                                <span style="display: block;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                                <span style="display: block; padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>


                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>


        <!-- mobile view -->
        <table id="mobile" border="1px solid #f2f2f2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style=" clear: both !important; margin: 0 auto !important; width: 100% !important; max-width: 450px !important; overflow: hidden; overflow-y: hidden;">
                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style=" border-collapse: collapse;">

                        <tr id="date">
                            <th style="padding-top: 20px;">example text</th>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" style="padding: 0; overflow-x: hidden; vertical-align: middle;">
                                <img id="header" src="assets/example.gif" style="width: 100% !important; display: block !important;" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" style="padding: 0; overflow-x: hidden; vertical-align: middle;">
                                <img id="planter" src="assets/example.gif" style="width: 100% !important; display: block !important;" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding: 20px;">
                                <span style="display: block; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 200; text-transform: uppercase; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px; color: #f36b22;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                                <span style="display: block; font-size: 35px; font-weight: 900; line-height: 1; text-transform: uppercase; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                                <span style="display: block; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 200; padding-bottom: 0px;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr style="padding: 0; background: #ffffff;">
                            <td style="padding: 0px; border: none;">
                                <a href='#' style="cursor: default;"><img id="trend-top" src="assets/example.png" style="display: block;"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>


                        <tr style="color: #504e4b;">
                            <td style="padding: 0px; width: 50%; background-color: #fccb03; vertical-align: top;">
                                <a href='#' style="cursor: default;"><img id="trend-bottom" src="assets/example.png" style="display: block;"></a>
                                <span style="display: block; height: 10px;"></span>
                                <span style="display: block; font-size: 28px; font-weight: 900; line-height: 1; text-transform: uppercase; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 20px;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                                <span style="display: block; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-bottom: 50px; font-weight: 200; color: #504e4b;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img id="trend-wheels" src="assets/example.gif" style="display: block; width: 100%;">
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" style="background: #ffffff;">
                                <img id="display-ideas" src="assets/example.png" style="max-width: 170px; display: block; width: 100%;">
                                <span style="display: block; font-size: 28px; font-weight: 900; line-height: 1; text-transform: uppercase; margin-top: 30px; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 20px; text-align: left;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                                <span style="display: block; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-bottom: 0px; font-weight: 200; color: #504e4b; text-align: left;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img id="pot-stand" src="assets/example.png" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto; padding: 20px 0px 40px 0px; max-width: 300px; width: 90%">
                                <a href='#' style="cursor: default;"><img src="assets/example.png" align="right" style="display: block;"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr align="right" style="padding: 0; background: #f36b22; color: #ffffff;">
                            <td style="padding: 0px;">
                                <a href='#' style="cursor: default;"><img src="assets/example.png" style="display: block;"></a>
                                <a href='#' style="cursor: default;"><img src="assets/example.png" align="right" style="display: block;"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr align="right" style="padding: 0; background: #f36b22; color: #ffffff;">
                            <td>
                                <span style="display: block; font-size: 28px; font-weight: 900; line-height: 1; text-transform: uppercase; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 35px; text-align: left;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                                <span style="display: block; padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 20px; padding-bottom: 50px; font-weight: 200; text-align: left;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr style="color: #504e4b;">
                            <td align="center" style="padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px;">
                                <span style="display: block;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                                <span style="display: block; padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hiding and unhiding elements in emails is tricky business.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the mso-rules to your hide and un-hide. You can use basic break points as well, but I have found that also using the `@media screen and (max-width:XXpx)` is a better solution since most people don't carry around laptops that are less than 450 pixels wide.

Email design and development is pure a totally mixed bag, and I wish you luck.

All in all I would not take this approach to hiding and unhiding content. Outlook will ignore it entirely and Gmail will do (as you know) unpredictable things.

Here's link to a basic template I made [Email template](https://github.com/seanrawles/Mailchimp_Template) that might help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

        <title></title>

        <style>
     #outlook a{
   padding:0;
  }
  .ReadMsgBody{
   width:100%;
  }
  body{
   width:100% !important;
   min-width:100%;
   -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
   -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  }
  v*{
      behavior:url(#default#VML);
   display:inline-block;
  }
  .ExternalClass{
   width:100%;
  }
  td{
   border-collapse: collapse!important;
  }
  .ExternalClass,
  .ExternalClass p,
  .ExternalClass span,
  .ExternalClass font,
  .ExternalClass td,
  .ExternalClass div{
   line-height:100%;
  }
  a img{
   border:none;
  }
  a {
   text-decoration:none !important;
  }
  img{
   display:block;
   outline:none;
   text-decoration:none;
   border:none; 
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
  }
  table{
   border-spacing:0;
   border-collapse: collapse !important;
   mso-table-lspace:0pt;
   mso-table-rspace:0pt;
  }
        @media (min-width: 451px) {
            table#mobile {
                display: none !important;
   max-height: 0px;
   font-size: 0px;
   overflow: hidden;
   mso-hide: all;
            }
        }

        @media (max-width: 450px) {
            table#desktop {
               display: none !important;
   max-height: 0px;
   font-size: 0px;
   overflow: hidden;
   mso-hide: all;
            }

            table#mobile {
                display: inline !important;
            }
        }

        </style>

    </head>


    <body style="width: 100% !important; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 13.5px; line-height: 1.4; font-family: Helvetica; overflow-x: hidden;">
        <table id="desktop" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="1px solid black">
            <tr>
                <td  style="display: block; clear: both !important; margin: 0 auto !important; width: 600px !important; overflow: hidden;">
                    <table  border="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;">

                        <tr style="">
                            <th>

                            </th>
                            <th style="padding-top: 20px;">
                                <span style="color: #504e4b;"/>
                                    example text                            
                                </span>
                            </th>
                        </tr>

                        <tr style="padding: 0; background: #ffffff; color: #504e4b;">
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <a href='#' style="cursor: default;"><img src="assets/example.gif" style="display: block;"></a>
                                <a href='#' style="cursor: default;"><img src="assets/example.gif" style="display: block; pointer-events: none; cursor: default;"></a>
                                <span style="display: block; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 200; text-transform: uppercase; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 30px; color: #f36b22;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                                <span style="display: block; font-size: 35px; font-weight: 900; line-height: 1; text-transform: uppercase; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 30px;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                                <span style="display: block; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 200; padding-left: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr style="padding: 0; background: #ffffff;">
                            <td style="width: 50%; padding: 0px; border: none;">
                                <a href='#' style="cursor: default;"><img src="assets/example.png" style="display: block;"></a>
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 0px; border: none;">

                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr style="height: 415px; color: #504e4b;">
                            <td style="padding: 0px; width: 50%; background-color: #fccb03; vertical-align: top;">
                                <a href='#' style="cursor: default;"><img src="assets/example.png" style="display: block;"></a>
                                <span style="display: block; height: 10px;"></span>
                                <span style="display: block; font-size: 28px; font-weight: 900; line-height: 1; text-transform: uppercase; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 20px;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                                <span style="display: block; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-bottom: 50px; font-weight: 200; color: #504e4b;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 0px;">
                                <a href='#' style="cursor: default;"><img src="assets/example.gif" style="display: block;"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr style="vertical-align: top; color: #504e4b;">
                            <td style="width: 50%; padding: 0px; border: none;">
                                <a href='#' style="cursor: default;"><img src="assets/example.png" style="display: block;"></a>
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: right; padding: 0px;">
                                <a href='#' style="cursor: default;"><img src="assets/example.png" align="right" style="display: block; padding-right: 20px;"></a>
                                <span style="display: block; font-size: 28px; font-weight: 900; line-height: 1; text-transform: uppercase; margin-top: 180px; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-right: 20px;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                                <span style="display: block; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-bottom: 40px; font-weight: 200; color: #504e4b;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                                <a href='#' style="cursor: default;"><img src="assets/example.png" align="right" style="display: block;"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr style="padding: 0; background: #f36b22; color: #ffffff;">
                            <td>
                                <span style="display: block; font-size: 28px; font-weight: 900; line-height: 1; text-transform: uppercase; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 30px; padding-top: 50px;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                                <span style="display: block; padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 20px; padding-bottom: 50px; font-weight: 200;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 0px;">
                                <a href='#' style="cursor: default;"><img src="assets/example.png" style="display: block;"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr style="padding: 0; background: #ffffff;">
                            <td style="padding: 0px; border: none;">

                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 50%; padding: 0px; border: none;">
                                <a href='#' style="cursor: default;"><img src="assets/example.png" align="right" style="display: block;"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr style="color: #504e4b;">
                            <td align="center" colspan="2" style="padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px;">
                                <span style="display: block;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                                <span style="display: block; padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>


                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>


        <!-- mobile view -->
        <table id="mobile" border="1px solid #f2f2f2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style=" clear: both !important; margin: 0 auto !important; width: 100% !important; max-width: 450px !important; overflow: hidden; overflow-y: hidden;">
                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style=" border-collapse: collapse;">

                        <tr id="date">
                            <th style="padding-top: 20px;">example text</th>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" style="padding: 0; overflow-x: hidden; vertical-align: middle;">
                                <img id="header" src="assets/example.gif" style="width: 100% !important; display: block !important;" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" style="padding: 0; overflow-x: hidden; vertical-align: middle;">
                                <img id="planter" src="assets/example.gif" style="width: 100% !important; display: block !important;" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding: 20px;">
                                <span style="display: block; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 200; text-transform: uppercase; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px; color: #f36b22;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                                <span style="display: block; font-size: 35px; font-weight: 900; line-height: 1; text-transform: uppercase; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                                <span style="display: block; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 200; padding-bottom: 0px;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr style="padding: 0; background: #ffffff;">
                            <td style="padding: 0px; border: none;">
                                <a href='#' style="cursor: default;"><img id="trend-top" src="assets/example.png" style="display: block;"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>


                        <tr style="color: #504e4b;">
                            <td style="padding: 0px; width: 50%; background-color: #fccb03; vertical-align: top;">
                                <a href='#' style="cursor: default;"><img id="trend-bottom" src="assets/example.png" style="display: block;"></a>
                                <span style="display: block; height: 10px;"></span>
                                <span style="display: block; font-size: 28px; font-weight: 900; line-height: 1; text-transform: uppercase; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 20px;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                                <span style="display: block; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-bottom: 50px; font-weight: 200; color: #504e4b;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img id="trend-wheels" src="assets/example.gif" style="display: block; width: 100%;">
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" style="background: #ffffff;">
                                <img id="display-ideas" src="assets/example.png" style="max-width: 170px; display: block; width: 100%;">
                                <span style="display: block; font-size: 28px; font-weight: 900; line-height: 1; text-transform: uppercase; margin-top: 30px; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 20px; text-align: left;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                                <span style="display: block; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-bottom: 0px; font-weight: 200; color: #504e4b; text-align: left;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img id="pot-stand" src="assets/example.png" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto; padding: 20px 0px 40px 0px; max-width: 300px; width: 90%">
                                <a href='#' style="cursor: default;"><img src="assets/example.png" align="right" style="display: block;"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr align="right" style="padding: 0; background: #f36b22; color: #ffffff;">
                            <td style="padding: 0px;">
                                <a href='#' style="cursor: default;"><img src="assets/example.png" style="display: block;"></a>
                                <a href='#' style="cursor: default;"><img src="assets/example.png" align="right" style="display: block;"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr align="right" style="padding: 0; background: #f36b22; color: #ffffff;">
                            <td>
                                <span style="display: block; font-size: 28px; font-weight: 900; line-height: 1; text-transform: uppercase; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 35px; text-align: left;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                                <span style="display: block; padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 20px; padding-bottom: 50px; font-weight: 200; text-align: left;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr style="color: #504e4b;">
                            <td align="center" style="padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px;">
                                <span style="display: block;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                                <span style="display: block; padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;">
                                    example text
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, ultimately I couldn't find a way to circumvent gmail's protocols and ended up changing the design of the email to just have one version that works for both desktop and mobile instead of one design per platform. Thanks for your input.